# Set dynamic env LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Is it good practice set dynamic env in the AppServiceProvider?
I have to set the dynamic name of the type of environment.

Example:

In the .env file

```
// Env set in AppServiceProvider
APP_ENV_DESCRIPTION=
```

And in AppServiceProvider register() method:

```
// Set enviroment description
if (App::environment('local')) {
    Config::set('app.env_description', 'Ambiente di sviluppo');   
} else {
    Config::set('app.env_description', 'Ambiente di staging');
}
```

Comment: yes it's one of the practices that we should use

Comment: Why not just set it in your `.env` file? So if your environment is "staging", "development" or "production" you want to set the description to something containing "staging"? Even in "production"?

Comment: i want to automate the whole thing. I will automatically change the description through the ENV. The description show in application dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem and I wrote my own method, I hope it will help you out to do dynamic modifications in .env file.
You will need to pass key and their value to **setEnvironmentValue** function and it will update your value.
Cheers!

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function setEnvironmentValue($envKey, $envValue)
    {
      $envFile = app()->environmentFilePath();
      $str = file_get_contents($envFile);
      $array = explode("\r\n",$str);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
          $index = explode('=', $value);
            if ($index[0] == $envKey)
              $array[$key] = $index[0].'="'.$envValue.'"';
        }

        $str = implode("\r\n",$array);
        $fp = fopen($envFile, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $str);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    public function setEnv(Request $request)
    {
        $this->setEnvironmentValue($request->key, $request->value);

        return back();
    }
}
```